# Weird story involving moving, talking standing stones

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

Asking for a friend (really):

> OK, creepy story, crawling up a hedgerow to the top of a hill, standing stones which move, but freeze if you look at them directly. And they talk. Any ideas?

Original inquirer not much of a film/television viewer, so definitely a story.

Comment: Hi. Your wording might be confusing to some. Are you sure your friend wasn't asking for help writing the story?

Comment: Could you ask your friend for some additional details? Currently, this question is not very detailed, at all. We would need some more information before being able to answer.

Comment: FWIW, the premise sounds a bit like the "Weeping Angels" of Doctor Who, which appeared in more than a couple of episodes.